# TYPO3 seo no sitemap ?type=1533906435

Tags: typo3, typo3-10.x

Typo3 10.4.16

I am not able to create a sitemap.xml with the system extension SEO.
My current understanding is, that the only requirement is, to install SEO and include static template. Than I should be able to see a sitemap with `https://yourdomain.com/?type=1533906435`. But I always see my start page and not a sitemap.
Under `EXT:seo/Resources/Public/CSS/Sitemap.xsl` I see a file, but it is 1 month old has nothing to do with my site.
Is there any possibility to trigger seo to generate a new sitemap?

*Output from Template -> Template Analyzer*:

[image: Template Analyzer]

Or what can I check?

**Edit 2021-06-14 10:10**

I have moved up the seo static template to to top. No change!

Yes there is a redirect from [www.mysite.xyz](http://www.mysite.xyz) to [www.mysite.xyz/startseite](http://www.mysite.xyz/startseite)!
When I use a different type, no changes.
This is the a screen shoot from the Object browser:
[image]

**Edit 2021-06-14 11:00**

I am a big step forward. The problem was the redirect, thanks to Richard.

But now I have a problem with the redirect. Even if I include under sites->StticRoutes a new Route with sitemap.xml it is not working together with the redirect.

So the next I tried is the new feature of seo to set xslFile. So I used `xslFile = sitemap.xsl` and also tried `xslFile = /sitemap.xsl` but both are not working!

Is it not possible to define a xslFile on the root?

Comment: Did you include static from ext for sure? also, did you clear caches? That feature *should* work out of the box. Optionally try to move included down (or up) on the list.

Comment: So when accessing your site with the type of the XML sitemap you get the homepage? Are there any redirects in place? What happens when you enter a complete different type?

Comment: Just to make sure that this is really what gets loaded and that it is not in any case overwritten - check the `seo_sitemap` object in `Template -> TypoScript Object Browser`.

Comment: See Edit from 2021-06-14 10:10